# How to change the Application Delegate class?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In every iOS app there is an App Delegate class, meaning one of the classes in the app has to implement the delegate methods for the application events such as `didFinishLaunching:` and so forth. Usually the class name contains "AppDelegate".

The App Delegate class is a subclass of `UIApplicationDelegate` on iOS or `NSApplicationDelegate` on the Mac.

```
class AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate {

}
```

Let's say I want to implement the App Delegate methods in a different class than the original one Xcode created and named for me. How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the same by modifying the parameters to the `UIApplicationMain` function present in the **main.m** file:

```
UIApplicationMain(argc,argv,nil,nil);
```

The last parameter takes the name of the class which is implementing the **UIApplicationDelegate** protocol.

So the default implementation looks something like:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
```

After modifying it will be something like:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([< Your class name will go here > class]));
[pool release];
return retVal;
```

Comment: I don't know if it's still relevant, but I don't find any main.m file in my project

Answer (score 4):

I achieved this in Swift by changing the `AppDelegate`'s default template implementation:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

replace with:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class MyAppAppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

See the new class name.