# Renaming AppDelegate.h hazards

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I renamed `AppDelegate.h` in my iOS application project.

The project is still working but the delegate name turned red and a small question mark button appeared.

Will this cause problems in the future? Why did the App Delegate turn red?

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project? Option+Shift+Command+K

Comment: Does your project build and run fine?

Comment: yes everything is ok but the appDelegate turns red will this create any problem later ?

Comment: First of all.. why did you require to rename AppDelegate? If you need to use yourName instead, simply change the delegate for the window and  controllers to your and leave the appDelegate file as it is.  This is the design pattern or way I follow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061239/how-to-change-the-application-delegate-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AppDelegate is the object that act for the whole application, i.e., it is an object that confirms to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol. E.g., it should react if the application becomes active (`– applicationDidBecomeActive:`is fired) etc.

The object's name does not matter. If a file turns red in Xcode it means that Xcode can not find the actual file. Maybe you changed the name or moved it outside of Xcode. Usually it helps to remove the red file and re-add it.

Comment: i use refactor in xcode to rename appDelegate but it turns red. I checked the file in the folder directory its similar to the refactored name

Comment: @sophia "Similar" is not sufficient, it must be the same.

Comment: Exact Matthias but its working too weird

Comment: Well, for **compilation** it is sufficient if the name in the header matches the actual file name. IDEs as XCode add some comfort layer, e.g. for versioning. The red name signs an inconsistency within XCode meta data, but it does not necessarily implies an inconsistency in the actual code (i.e., you _may_ be still able to compile)

Comment: but if i want to upload it on appstore, it will still work ?

Comment: I have never tried, but it might work. However, it is always a good idea to keep your project in a consistent state. If cleaning (see  Gabriele's comment) or remove/add (see my answer) does not help, you can organize it at the right panel.